# Notification that brings to activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm doing stuff by clicking the notification appeared which can allow to straightly access to the activity that I  needed(in this case I want to access to `RealtimeData.java` activity).

Btw, is that possible to display the notification instead of opening the activity for showing up the notification (the notification seems not to pop-out if I didn't enter to the specific activity. Notification pop-out if and only if I access to the RealtimeData activity) Thank a lot.

```
public class RealtimeData extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatebase;
private TextView mTempView; @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_realtime_data);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deletebutton)                     
mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading");
mTempView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);

mDatebase.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String temp = datasnap.child("airtemperature").getValue(String.class);
                if (Float.valueOf(temp) >= 24 && Float.valueOf(temp) <= 30) {
                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Normal");
                }
                else if (Float.valueOf(temp) < 24)
                {
                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal Low ");
                    NotificationCompat.Builder wbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RealtimeData.this);
                    wbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.impressive);
                    wbuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
                    wbuilder.setContentText("Air Temperature lowly abnormal!!");
                    wbuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    wbuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000});
                    wbuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN,3000,3000);
                    wbuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, wbuilder.build());
                }

                else if (Float.valueOf(temp) > 30)
                {
                    mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal High ");
                    NotificationCompat.Builder wbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RealtimeData.this);
                    wbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.impressive);
                    wbuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
                    wbuilder.setContentText("Air temperature highly abnormal!!");
                    wbuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    wbuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000});
                    wbuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN,3000,3000);
                    wbuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, wbuilder.build());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: Error");

        }
    });;
```

Comment: You have a detailed guide in official Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are launching the notification from inside the activity so obviously it will only show when using the RealtimeData activity.

If you want a notification to show without any activity open, you will have to send one yourself.

Notifications can be sent using a number of services like
Parse (you have to manage your own server now)

Firebase Notifications ( Send notifications both downstream and upstream)

OneSignal

PubNub

These are the ones that i know, might be others if you google search.

Using any of these, you will have to post a notification to be delivered to the device you want from your own server or via a management console these services provide.

I am currently using Firebase Services to send notifications to devices. All of the services above have a pretty good documentation regarding how to send notifications to apps :)

Comment: it there any documentation on how to doing the firebase notifications?thanks

Comment: but mostly the documentation/demo that I had seen shows the message only can be send manualy (I wish to see any example the can send the notification automatically). In my case, I need notification to be sent automatically once high temperature is triggered

Comment: You can set up a webapp which can send the notification when called. Once your temperature is hit, call that service. I don't know how exactly the temp is sensed or what your logic app is so i can only hint at the solution. You will have to figure out how to send it buddy. I personally even have cronjobs which send notifications at various times. I have alarms which trigger notifications. So basically it depends on your use case. Choose what is best for you

Comment: :) glad i could help somewhat :) please accept the answer if it helped.